# iOS 10 blur filter css

Tags: blur, ios10

I have a responsive web application that includes  some blurred images(using blur filter), to follow from here everything working perfectly till I did my iOS update to version 10.

any idea to fix this issue or a similar issue with the blur filter that can help me out will be appreciated?

```
.caption-container {
height: 70px;
left: -3px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 0 56px;
-webkit-filter: blur(8px);
filter: blur(8px);
width: 270px;
margin-top: -70px;
z-index: -1;
position: inherit;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: the blur effect is not showing up - try out the below url : http://lmpapp.herokuapp.com  from an iPhone with iOS 10 and from iPhone with iOS then you will see the issue clearly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of my users met the same problem within my hybrid mobile app, the blur css property is not handled by IOS10 for unknown reasons.

Instead of blurring, in my case, it just makes the whole div white.

I don't have an IOS10, but could you try with the property:

```
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
```

Comment: this is sad ... there should be a workaround for this issue I hope so

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe you can try with the css property: -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
backdrop-filter: blur(10px); it seems to be working for safari only.

Comment: -webkit-backdrop-filter works perfectly on iOS Safari